# How to set multiple default values for multiple select in flask-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, flask

**flask view:**

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html',
                           form=form,
                           working_days=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday'])
```

**hello.html -** I am using Flask-Bootstrap

```
<form class="form-group" action="..." method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.days) }} <!-- saturday, sunday, monday, tuesday, wensday, thursday, friday -->
</form>
```

**results in:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="days" multiple name="days" required>
    <option value="saturday">saturday</option>
    <option value="sunday">sunday</option>
    <option value="monday">monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">wednesday</option>
    <option value="thursday">thursday</option>
    <option value="friday">friday</option>
</select>
```

my question is how can i set default values (`working_days`) to the `form.days` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer (pure javascript), so all I needed to do was looping over the options values and check if any matches the values in `working_days`, if so, I will add `attr('selected', true)`

where `$('.form-group')` is the closest parent that already existed when the page loaded.

```
for (var i = 1; i < $('.form-group').find('option').length + 1; i++){ 
  if ({{ working_days | safe }}.indexOf($('.form-group').find('option:nth-child(' + i + ')').val()) > -1) {
    $('.form-group').find('option:nth-child(' + i + ')').attr("selected", true)
  }
}
```

:)